# Can I find #define with clang-query?

Tags: clang-query

I know that `#define`s are processed by the preprocessor and not the compiler that creates the AST. But anyways, the LLVM/clang toolchain could somehow retain that information internally.

Can I query for `#define` with clang-query? If so, how?